# How to change when Lotus Notes starts prompting for password change?

Tags: passwords, lotus-notes

My default Lotus Notes installation prompts me to change the password 30 days before it expires. Every time I open Lotus Notes during this 30 day period, it starts with a dialog box, and no option to disable it. Is there some way I could change this duration to say, 7 days before the expiration.

I have gone through the File -> Preferences, but cannot seem to find this setting. Searching on the internet did not get me anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change in this within the client, it's defined by the Security policy which set by the Lotus Notes Administrator. If policies aren't in use then the default is 30 days.

source: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_DYNAMICALLY_PUSHING_ADMIN_ECLS_OVER.html